# landscape mode change image on layout

Tags: android, layout, imageview, landscape, screen-orientation

hello guys my problem is the next: I have an ImageView that at launch of the application load an image (default_image) and then the user can change it and see more pictures, but when I change the screen orientation in my ImageView displays the image to begin loading in OnCreate (default_image) and not the current_image and do not know why?

ps: I do not have a layout in the layout-land folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the orientation is considered a configuration change. You'll need to handle the onConfigurationChanged event in order to persist the user's position in the image collection (or whatever you're using). Check out the developer guide on handling these situations. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html